# How to get a Field to link straight to Edit Item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a field that I have set `linkToItem="TRUE"` so that when it is clicked it takes me to the `Dispform.aspx`. I want to make this field when clicked to take me to the `Editform.aspx` instead as the display form is not needed in the system we have built.